# Python - Convert List

Tags: python, maya, mel

command cmds.polyInfo (fe=True) output:

```
[u'FACE     64:     48     49     50     51     52     54     64     74     84     94    104 \n']
```

How to convert it to a list of this kind?

```
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 104]
```

I suspect that it is necessary to use re.findall

I would be grateful for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use `re` module, simply use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) instead:

```
In [78]: lst=[u'FACE     64:     48     49     50     51     52     54     64     74     84     94    104 \n']

In [79]: [int(i) for i in lst[0].split(':')[1].split()]
Out[79]: [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 104]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alist=[u'FACE     64:     48     49     50     51     52     54     64     74     84     94    104 \n']
```

Using map and join:

```
map(lambda x:int(x), "".join(alist).split(':')[1].split())
```

Using list comprehension:

```
[int(x) for x in "".join(alist).split(':')[1].split()]
```

Output:

```
[48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 104]
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a little splitting:

```
face = cmds.polyInfo(fe=True)[0]
[int(v) for v in face.split(':', 1)[-1].split()]
```

This takes the output of the `cmds.polyInfo()` method, takes the first element, takes everything after the first `:` and splits that up on whitespace. The result is a list of strings (`['48', '49', ...]`), which the list comprehension then turns into a list of integers instead.